# Best practices for deploying/updating containers with Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to understand how I should deploy containers with Kubernetes. I am new at this topic so at this moment I am testing all these ideas in a virtual machine.

I'm using Git, Jenkins, Docker, Docker Hub and Kubernetes.

Also, I have a Master node and only one Slave node.

I created a YAML deploy file to start the pod and create a new container.

```sh
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Then I expose the deploy.

```sh
kubectl expose deployment my-app --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-app
```

YAML File for deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appcontainer
        image: repository:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8085
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Now that I have all working, for example, I give a new update on the image and I need to update this new image, for example, 1.0 to 1.1, on the deployment done. I need to know the proper way to do this action.

Because I think I'm doing it wrong like I'm trying to smash the image on the container created with the new image and I don't know if the proper way is deploying with a new YAML file and if Kubernetes builds a new container with that image and consequently kill the old deploy, but I don't know how I can do that if this the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to [update a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) with new image will be to run:

```
kubectl set image deployment/my-app appcontainer=repository:1.1 --record
```

This way it will first create a new pod(s) with newer version of image and once successfully deployed it will terminate old pod or pods depending on number of replicas you have specified in the `replicas` field.

You can check status of the update by running

```
kubectl rollout status deployment.v1.apps/my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is called `Rolling update`. You can have the `deployment.yaml` updated like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
      role: master
      tier: backend
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appcontainer
        image: repository:1.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8085
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Please note the rolling update configuration:

```
strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 0
  type: RollingUpdate
```

`maxSurge` indicates the number of extra pods that can be run during the deployment rollout. `maxUnavailable` is about the number of pods that can be taken down during the rollout. These values can either be an integer value - exact number of pods or a percentage of pods. You can adjust these values to suit your usecase.

Then you can change the image tag in the yaml and do `kubectl apply` to update the image.